# Rails 4 API with devise and doorkeeper - Android app authentication

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I have developed simple Ruby on Rails based API. I want to use resources from my API with my Android application. My Rails backend uses devise and doorkeeper for OAuth 2 based authentication. How can I use authentication process from my Android app. Do I need to use WebView or ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definitely use token based authentication. You should follow the guide from Doorkeeper's documentation, it's well documented there.

https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Interacting-as-an-OAuth-client-with-Doorkeeper

Also, you should check how to implement this on android.

http://docs.huihoo.com/android/4.2/training/id-auth/authenticate.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this is nice for a start. I hope I will figure it out :)